# Need Help with inserting code

Tags: php

I am not a programmer by no means.  I am trying to figure out how to get this code inserted into profile.php

```
 $author_id = get_query_var('author');

if($author_id){
echo do_shortcode("[photosmash gallery_type='contributor' author=" . $author_id . " no_form=true]");
}
```

**Below is profile.php code:**

```
<?php global $mngl_user, $mngl_friend, $mngl_options; ?>
<?php $display_profile = ( $user->privacy == 'public' or 
                           MnglUser::is_logged_in_and_an_admin() or 
                           MnglUser::is_logged_in_and_visible() ); ?>

<table class="mngl-profile-table">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" class="mngl-profile-table-col-1 mngl-valign-top">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <?php echo $avatar; ?>
            <?php echo $mngl_friends_controller->display_add_friend_button($mngl_user->id, $user->id); ?>
            <?php echo do_action('mngl-profile-display',$user->id); ?>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" class="mngl-valign-top">
            <?php if($display_profile) { ?>

              <?php if(isset($mngl_options->field_visibilities['profile_front']['bio']) and !empty($user->bio)) { ?>
                <p class="mngl-profile-bio"><?php echo MnglBoardsHelper::format_message($user->bio); ?></p>
              <?php } ?>
              <div class="mngl-profile-information">
              <?php if(isset($mngl_options->field_visibilities['profile_front']['name']) and !empty($user->first_name) and ($user->first_name != $user->screenname)) { ?>
                <p class="mngl-profile-field"><strong><?php _e('Name', 'mingle'); ?>:</strong><br/><?php echo wptexturize(stripslashes($user->first_name)); ?>
                <?php if(!empty($user->last_name)){ ?>
                <?php echo " " . wptexturize(stripslashes($user->last_name)); ?>
                <?php } ?>
                </p>
              <?php } ?>
              <?php if(isset($mngl_options->field_visibilities['profile_front']['sex']) and !empty($user->sex)) { ?>
                <p class="mngl-profile-sex"><strong><?php _e('Gender', 'mingle'); ?>:</strong><br/><?php echo $user->sex_display; ?></p>
              <?php } ?>

              <?php if(isset($mngl_options->field_visibilities['profile_front']['location']) and !empty($user->location)) { ?>
                <p class="mngl-profile-location"><strong><?php _e('Location', 'mingle'); ?>:</strong><br/><?php echo wptexturize($user->location); ?></p>
              <?php } ?>
              <?php if(isset($mngl_options->field_visibilities['profile_front']['birthday']) and !empty($user->birthday)) { ?>
                <p class="mngl-profile-location"><strong><?php _e('Birthday', 'mingle'); ?>:</strong><br/><?php echo wptexturize($user->birthday); ?></p>
              <?php } ?>
              <?php if(isset($mngl_options->field_visibilities['profile_front']['url']) and !empty($user->url)) { ?>
                <p class="mngl-profile-url"><strong><?php _e('Website', 'mingle'); ?>:</strong><br/><?php echo make_clickable($user->url); ?></p>
              <?php } ?>
              </div>
            <?php } ?>
            <p><strong><?php _e('Friends', 'mingle'); ?>:</strong><div class="mngl-profile-friend-grid-wrap"><?php echo $mngl_friends_controller->display_friends_grid($user->id); ?></div></p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" class="mngl-profile-table-col-2">
      <table class="mngl-profile-body">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="mngl-profile-name"><?php echo $user->screenname; ?></div>
            <?php 
              if(!$display_profile)
                require( MNGL_VIEWS_PATH . '/mngl-boards/private.php' );
            ?>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <?php if($display_profile) { ?>
            <td valign="top" width="100%"><div class="mngl-board"><?php echo $mngl_boards_controller->display($user->id); ?></div></td>
          <?php } ?>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

The new code needs to be enclosed in `<?php` and `?>`. Then insert it into any free HTML area, for example between the empty `<td>` and `</td>` at the bottom. If it looks better elsewhere, move it. For non-programmers this is a trial end error method. Just take care not to insert it within any `<?php if(...` and `<?php } ?>` areas.